# Insert SVG-File in mysql and retrieve it

Tags: mysql

i have created a svg-graph, und i tried to insert it into my database, and retrieve it dynamically, but without success.
Can somebody please show me or give me some suggestions how to do this.
Thanks             Knowhow

Answer (score 4):

SVG files are plain text files - just store their contents in a field of type `TEXT`.